# How to launch Navigator in cordova in ios

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I have an app where (AngularJs+cordova), I need to get current position of the user and navigate to destination using google maps.

I am unable to get it work in iOS:

I have tried:

```css
/* $scope.launchNavigator = function() {
    
    console.log("$scope.launchNavigator...");
    
        var deviceType = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))  == "iPad" ? "iPad" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))  == "iPhone" ? "iPhone" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) == "Android" ? "Android" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) == "BlackBerry" ? "BlackBerry" : "null";
        
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure);
        
        if(deviceType === 'Android'){
          cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        }
        else {
          // vm.showGPSAlert = true;
          // vm.GPSTextAlert = "Please enable Location Services in Settings and Try again"
          //function onDeviceReady() {
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
            //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
          //}
        }
    }

    function onRequestSuccess(success){
      function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
      }
    }

      function onSuccess(position){
          console.log('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
        
            latitudeStart = position.coords.latitude;
            longitudeStart = position.coords.longitude;

            launchnavigator.isAppAvailable(launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS, function(isAvailable){
              var app;
              console.log("Location navigate .lat." + )
              if(isAvailable){
                  app = launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS;
              }else{
                  console.warn("Google Maps not available - falling back to user selection");
                  app = launchnavigator.APP.USER_SELECT;
              }
              launchnavigator.navigate([vm.dest.latitude,vm.dest.longitude], {
                  app: app,
                  start: [latitudeStart,longitudeStart]
              });
          });
        }
        
        function onError(){
          
      }

      function onRequestFailure(error){
            console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
            if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
                if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
                    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
                }
            }
      }*/
```

<--the above doesn't work for both iOS and Android-->

For android, following works:

```css
      /*Get Direction*/

    function onDeviceReady() {
      //window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
      console.log("Hello... Device redy");

      var latitudeStart = '';
      var longitudeStart = '';

      $scope.launchNavigator = function() {
        
        function onRequestSuccess(success){
            console.log("Successfully requested accuracy: "+success.message);

            if(navigator.geolocation){ 
              console.log("navigator.geolocation works well");
            }
            else{
             console.log("navigator.geolocation doesnt works well");
            }

        console.log("Luanch navigate..");

        var onSuccess = function(position) {
        console.log('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
              'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
              'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
              'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
              'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
              'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
              'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
            
            latitudeStart = position.coords.latitude;
            longitudeStart = position.coords.longitude;

            launchnavigator.isAppAvailable(launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS, function(isAvailable){
              var app;
              if(isAvailable){
                  app = launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS;
              }else{
                  console.warn("Google Maps not available - falling back to user selection");
                  app = launchnavigator.APP.USER_SELECT;
              }
              launchnavigator.navigate([vm.dest.latitude,vm.dest.longitude], {
                  app: app,
                  start: [latitudeStart,longitudeStart]
              });
          });
        };

        // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
        //
        function onError(erro) {
            console.log('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{enableHighAccuracy:true});
      }

        function onRequestFailure(error){
            console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
            if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
                if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
                    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
                }
            }
        }

        cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


        
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

> the above doesn't work for both iOS and Android

Firstly, I would use [cordova-plugin-device](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) to determine the platform rather than user agent sniffing - it is more robust.

Secondly, it appears you have a function dependent on the `deviceready` event which is invoked on the successful outcome of a plugin result:

```
function onRequestSuccess(success){
  function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
  }
}
```

Cordova plugins are dynamically loaded before the `deviceready` event is invoked, so it's likely that the inner function is never invoked.

Thirdly, the success callback function for both `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled()` and `cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request()` appears to be `onRequestSuccess()`. 
Both of the former are invoked in serial synchrony but their callbacks are invoked asynchronously, so this is likely to lead to problems.

I would try something like this:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    console.log("onDeviceReady...");

    $scope.launchNavigator = function() {
        console.log("$scope.launchNavigator...");

        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
            if(!enabled){
                if(device.platform === 'Android'){
                  cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(getCurrentPosition, 
                    function(error){
                        console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
                        if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
                            if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
                                cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
                            }
                        }
                    }, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                }
                else {
                  // vm.showGPSAlert = true;
                  // vm.GPSTextAlert = "Please enable Location Services in Settings and Try again"
                  //function onDeviceReady() {
                    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
                    //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
                  //}
                }
            }else{
                getCurrentPosition();
            }

        }, function onLocationEnabledFailure(error){
            console.error("Failed to check if location is enabled");
        });

        function getCurrentPosition(){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        }

        function onSuccess(position){
          console.log('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');

            latitudeStart = position.coords.latitude;
            longitudeStart = position.coords.longitude;

            launchnavigator.isAppAvailable(launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS, function(isAvailable){
              var app;
              console.log("Location navigate .lat." + )
              if(isAvailable){
                  app = launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS;
              }else{
                  console.warn("Google Maps not available - falling back to user selection");
                  app = launchnavigator.APP.USER_SELECT;
              }
              launchnavigator.navigate([vm.dest.latitude,vm.dest.longitude], {
                  app: app,
                  start: [latitudeStart,longitudeStart]
              });
          });
        }

        function onError(positionError){
            // Handle Error
        }

    } //$scope.launchNavigator
}// onDeviceReady
```

In general, I would highly recommend using Safari Remote Debugging and Chrome Remote Debugging tools to debug your app while running on iOS and Android devices respectively. 
Using the step-through debugger with appropriate breakpoints will highlight issues such as those present in your code snippet.
See the [Debugging Cordova apps](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/#debugging-cordova-apps) section in the Cordova docs for details.